# Orthogonal Matrix question

Tags: matrices

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is an orthogonal matrix.

a) Prove that $A^{-1}=A^T$

b) show further that $a^2=d^2$ and that $b^2=c^2$. State th possible values of det$A$.

I've done part a, but I can't do part b. Please help.

Comment: an orthogonal matrix has columns mutually orthogonal and of unit length; so do the rows. that alone tells you that $a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + c^2 = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Use the multiplicativity of the determinant $\det AB = \det A \det B$:
$$1=\det (I)=\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T) \det (A)$$

Comment: But how do you know that $a^2=d^2$ and $c^2=b^2$?

Comment: Do you know the general formula for $A^{-1}$ if $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$?

Answer (score 0):

We know that for an orthorgonal matrix
$$A^{T}=A^{-1}$$
and 
$$\mathbf{A}^{-1}  =
\frac{1}{\det(\mathbf{A})} \begin{bmatrix}
\,\,\,d & \!\!-b \\ -c & \,a \\ 
\end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix}
\,\,\,d & \!\!-b \\ -c & \,a \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
If you let 
$$\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right]=\frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix}
\,\,\,d & \!\!-b \\ -c & \,a \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
And solve, you will be able to prove (b).